# Angular Material Unit Testing: Mocking a MatSelectChange event

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, mocking, jasmine

**Description**: I am writing unit tests for the following function:

```
updateUserStatus(event: MatSelectChange | any, reportID: number) {
    const matOption = (event.source.selected as MatOption);
    const option = matOption.value;
    this.setUserActions(reportID, option.id);
}
```

**Test Spec**

```
it('should test updateUserStatus', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'updateUserStatus').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(component, 'setUserActions').and.callFake(() => {});
    component.updateUserStatus({{MOCK_EVENT_HERE}}, 123456);
    expect(component.updateUserStatus).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.setUserActions).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

**Problem**: I am finding it hard to mock the 'event' argument which is an instance of 'MatSelectChange'.

### **What have I tried so far?**

**1. Copying 'event' value from browser console**

This gives me a:

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON.

**2. Create a new MatSelectChange instance**

The 'MatSelect' constructor requires 12-13 arguments oh my!. Don't know how to instantiate:

```
const selectChange = new MatSelectChange(new MatSelect(), 'Value');
```

*If any other detail is missing, please let me know if that will help in understanding it better.*

Comment: have you tried just creating a javascript object with the key fields that are needed for your code and the casting it as a MatSelectChange before sending it to the function in your test?

Comment: Don't spy on the thing you're supposed to be testing, or directly call methods on the component. What does `setUserActions` actually *do*? Test the *behaviour* of the component.

Comment: @NileshKesar Not yet, Will give it a go.

Comment: @jonrsharpe unit test should be small if function_A has code calling another function_B you shouldn't be testing the function_B code inside a test about function_A since there independent what you can test is it being called.

Comment: @PradeepVig if you need an example let me know.

Comment: @NileshKesar unit tests should be small, yes, but you also need to think about appropriate boundaries and interfaces to test at. The system under test here is the *component*, not a method on it - test doubles should be used for *collaborators*, like injected services, not just other methods on the component. You shouldn't have to rewrite your tests just because you rename a method that's only consumed within the component, for example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 'setUserActions' makes a POST call with selected User Action, however, I am more concerned with mocking the 'event' argument. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Why do you need to mock the *event*? Mock the service that makes the HTTP call for your component (or, if your component makes the call directly, *extract that to a service* then mock it), the event gets created when you simulate the interaction with the component through the template. Again, test doubles are for *collaborators*.

Comment: Also note https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice

Comment: @jonrsharpe I got what you are trying to communicate to me. Maybe I should rather not care about mocking sophisticated stuff and trigger such events from the template itself. I'll reshape my code and test it again.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still stuck on this, I would just send a plain JavaScript object.

Try:

```
it('should test updateUserStatus', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'updateUserStatus').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(component, 'setUserActions').and.callFake(() => {});
    event.source.selected
    const mockMatSelectChange = {
      event: {
        source: {
         selected: {
           value: {
             id: '123', // mock ID to whatever it should be
           }
         } 
       }
      }
    };
    component.updateUserStatus(mockMatSelectedChange, 123456);
    expect(component.updateUserStatus).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(component.setUserActions).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: That helped. Although I was trying to trigger this method from DOM action, did not succeed.